# p-value for the means of two samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

I have a sample of each of two distributions (not the same sample size, unknown population size) where all values are of type float (not categorical). I have calculated the means of my two samples. What test do I use in order to find the p-value of these two means so I can say if the difference is statistically significant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to assume that the distributions are normal, the standard test is an unpaired [Student's $t$ test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test). You should verify that this assumption e.g. with a [q-q plot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) and perhaps also a [normality test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test). If the distributions are too non-normal, the $t$ test results will not be meaningful.

If your distributions aren't normal and you don't have a good alternative parametric form, the most commonly used similar nonparametric test is the [Mann-Whitney $U$ test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test). This isn't testing quite the same thing, though; it's more like a test of a difference in medians. For most purposes this is fine.

I don't know of a nonparametric test for exactly the difference in means, though if e.g. your distribtutions are bounded in some fixed interval, you could probably construct a test with Hoeffding's inequality. In practice it would probably be fairly conservative.

Answer (score 0):

What are the sample sizes? 
If sample sizes are less than 50 then use t-test to test the significance of difference between the population means. Else you can use the z-test.

Comment: Sample sizes are very large, in the order of 200,000, which is probably about 10% of the population.